Patching holes less than 1.5 inches wide in wood panel walls

I am about to put wallpaper in this bathroom, but I don’t know the best way to patch these two holes in the wood panel wall. Both holes are about 1-3/8” wide, right by where the tiled shower starts and directly above the toilet. The holes were behind an old phone jack and a blank wall plate I removed.
Also, the patches don’t need to look good since they’ll be covered up with wallpaper soon, but I do need them to be smooth.

Use hole saw and cut out disks (from wood) that you use as inserts with some glue to keep in place

@Traveler might be easier to just get a hole saw big enough to span both holes, and make one big hole, then cut out another piece of some panel to use as a plug.  Or simply use an oscillating multitool to cut out a square.  A bigger hole will also let you put in a backing piece to create a lap joint rather than a butt joint.
